# How does Santa get the raw materials he uses to build toys?

Tags: santa-claus

Santa Claus builds toys in his workshop with the help of his elves. However, the North Pole is rather scarce in raw materials (e.g.wood, iron, copper) with which to build them. Where does he get these raw materials from?

Comment: can't he use some sort of magic. like a magic machine or something?

Comment: @RowynAlloway If it's consistent with magic that Santa and his elves already have (e.g. fitting into any size of chimney), then yes.

Answer (score 2):

The North Pole is poor in raw materials, correct, but the mass of elves working under Santa Inc. has an entire year to mine, chop, smelt and whatsoever all around the world.

And also Santa knows that, from a logistic point of view, production centers scattered around the globe make the task of producing the gifts way more easy.

Comment: Would you say that Santa Claus has legal arrangements with each of these countries? Or are Santa's elves illegally harvesting all these materials (and presumably avoiding prosecution due to threat of getting on his naughty list)?

Answer (score 1):

Santa sends his workers out around the world to gather resources and bring them back. Obviously these elves are disguised so that they don't *actually* look like elves.

The tricky part is finding a way to get the resources to and from the North Pole. That's where airport disturbances come in.

You remember just a few days ago, how Gatwick was shut down because of a drone threat? Yeah, that was just a ploy. If everyone's focused on finding the owner of the drone, and getting it out of Gatwick airspace for that matter, then nobody will notice the small aircraft being piloted out with the resources. These kinds of things happen quite often, actually: [Wellington](https://dronedj.com/2018/11/13/drone-wellington-airport/) in November; [Oporto](https://mavicpilots.com/threads/another-drone-in-the-airport.45618/) and [Crater Lake](https://www.heraldandnews.com/news/local_news/illegal-drone-flight-near-airport-raises-concern/article_d3814ad1-b05c-5db8-8fbc-cc8b43a97589.html) in August; [Cork Airport](https://www.rte.ie/news/munster/2017/0420/869022-cork-airport-drone/) last April; [Ben-Gurion](http://www.jewishpress.com/news/breaking-news/drone-shuts-down-ben-gurion-airport/2017/12/13/) last December; [Auckland](https://www.nzherald.co.nz/nz/news/article.cfm?c_id=1&objectid=12007484) in March.

Sadly it's not a foolproof plan; last October, a [plane was struck](https://ktla.com/2017/10/16/drone-crashes-into-passenger-plane-in-canada/) approaching Quebec City; the elves responsible have since been, um, reassigned.

Answer (score 0):

You think Santa and the elves actually build and distribute toys? When toys were simple dolls and puppets made of wood they were able to keep up with demand by carving pieces from the North Pole: it regrows during the rest of the year.

Now that children demand many, much more expensive, technical toys, they have long-since abandoned that idea.

These days they are reduced to appearing in shopping centres before Christmas. They listen to what the children want and then simply pass a note to the parents who have to make the actual purchase.